# Is there a way to put \showbox into the page?

Tags: boxes, logging, registers

I am reading the Texbook, and there in exercise 11.2 *(and the preceding page)* there is a conversation of exploring box structure. The idea is that it may be put into a register that is then logged.

I have managed to obtain the contents of the register with the box structure into the log or console, via this code:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{{\it Some text.\/}}
\showoutput
\showbox0
```

I wonder if I can have whatever it says in the console typeset to the printed page instead, automatically.

Comment: luatex yes (although not a built in function) other engines not so easily

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use `\showoutput` first in a separate file and then include the log (or part of the log) verbatim in your main document.